# C# Hand image with click integration

Tags: c#, winforms

In my program,i want to create a form with an image of a hand. now when the user clicks on each finger it will change color. any idea how to achieve this. 
Sample image below:
[image: Sample Image]

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried using picture box,but i cannot identify which finger has been clicked and changing color.

Comment: Of course you can't since picture box isn't for that. But you aren't being clear on your requirements. "will change color" doesn't tell us anything, which color? Arbitrary color? A random color from a predefined list? A specific color for each finger? The other hand will behave like the previus? Meaning that if it'll be subject to the same colors.

Comment: You have to make Each Finger with Label , Click On Each Lable Set BackGround Color. Also... First You have An Image Like Blnk Finger and set BackGround Image to Form.. then Set Transparent 100 % for Each Label First Time when Clicked On Label Changed to Trasparent 0% and Cahnge the BG Color of LAbel

Comment: The colors doesn't matter. I just want to identify the finger being clicked by changing its color. The color on the image are just identification for the boundaries of each finger where the mouse can click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the hands using a [GraphicsPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and use a separate GraphicsPath for each finger which you put in a list `fingerPaths`

Then when a user clicks your canvas, take the mouse coordinates (`Point mousePos`) and do a hittest like this:

```
foreach (GraphicsPath path in fingerPaths)
{
   if (path.IsVisible(mousePos)
   {
      // change color of path and invalidate your canvas
   }
}
```

Comment: i'll try this GraphicsPath.